# How to getElementById contents of ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get the contents of ng-repeat?

```
<div ng-repeat="w in quick.wint">
   <div id="wname"><strong>{{w.Name}}</strong></div>
   <div id="wcount">{{w.Count}} Open Queues</div>
</div>
```

I want to assign them to variable for printing document

```
var wname = document.getElementById('wname').innerHTML;
var wcount = document.getElementById('wcount').innerHTML;
var popupWin =window.open('','_blank','width=300,height=300');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()"><h1>Documentation</h1>' + wname + '</body></html>');
popupWin.document.close();
```

I want to format it on the document differently from the way it is displayed in the browser. So for example it is displayed in browser as:

```
<wname>
<wcount>
```

I want it to be displayed in the document as:

```
<wname> : <wcount>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs need to be unique in the document. Don't use IDs on repeated elements.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. How can I access each contents?

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript. Just format it with CSS.

Comment: @epascarello first format is for displayed on the browser. second format is for the document(docx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the index on each id like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="w in quick.wint; let i = index">
   <div id="wname-{{i}}"><strong>{{w.Name}}</strong></div>
   <div id="wcount-{{i}}">{{w.Count}} Open Queues</div>
</div>
```

So if you want to grab a specific row you would call it by the concatenated id:

```
var wname = document.getElementById('wname-1').innerHTML;
var wcount = document.getElementById('wcount-1').innerHTML;
```

---

But if you want all the contents then maybe you should use a class and use querySelectorAll - to get an array of the children?

```
<div ng-repeat="w in quick.wint">
   <div class="wname"><strong>{{w.Name}}</strong></div>
   <div class="wcount">{{w.Count}} Open Queues</div>
</div>

const wnames = document.querySelectorAll(".wname")
const wcounts = document.querySelectorAll(".wcount")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

Comment: Hello Thank you for taking interest in my plight. I have tried both solution but I can't seem to get desired result for both. On the first one, I am getting error of [$parse:syntax](angular1.4.3). On the second, I am getting [object nodelist] as result? I am not good with this, pardon my ignorance. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you using angular 1.4.3?

Go with the second option. just wrap `document.querySelectorAll(".wname")` with Array.from(...) like this: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".wname"))`

do the same with the other one

Comment: Thank you so much! Forgive me for further prodding the issue. However I am getting an empty result. When I tried to "console.log" it, I get zero(0) as output. What could I have done wrong?